# How to import really large numbers into R?

Tags: r, string, numeric

I tend to read a large number from a string input and then convert it into numeric format. However, I always get wrong output.

```
#the input string is: "31415926535897932384626433832795"
```

My code is like this:

```
input <- readLines("stdin", warn = F)
options(scipen = 10^6)
nums <- as.numeric(input)
cat(nums)
```

the output is like this, the original number has been modified. I don't get what happened when importing and converting the string into numeric?

```
31415926535897933290036940242944
```

Comment: The reason can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal but I don't want to close as duplicate because the answer to importing your numbers isn't in that thread.

Comment: Load the package `bit64`. That may fix your issue.

Comment: @Dason the linked-to qustion isn't relevant because that's about floating point numbers and OP has an integer.

Comment: @QianLi see also the `gmp` package for R.

Comment: @RobertDodier And yet it is relevant because they aren't storing it as integer.

Comment: @ Kristofersen , can you explain a bit more? I loaded the package     bit64, and used the function as.integer64(), still it cannot correctly convert the string into a number. Thanks.

Comment: @Dason I think you're needlessly jumping to conclusions here.

Comment: @Robert Dodier  `gmp` works perfectly for this. Problem solved! Thanks.